# Using alglib without compiling every time

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, alglib

I'm using some methods from the c++ AlgLib library. In other libraries I've used there were some instructions for installation, after which I could include .h files and compile with -l (e.g. using the GMP-library and compiling with -lgmp). However with alglib the only thing I've been able to get running is using a makefile and compiling all needed .cpp files - every time I compile my program. Here is an example of a makefile:

```
all:    
g++ name.cpp ap.cpp integration.cpp interpolation.cpp alglibinternal.cpp linalg.cpp
    alglibmisc.cpp specialfunctions.cpp solvers.cpp optimization.cpp -o name
```

As compiling all these files every time is relatively time consuming, is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the make feature.
Make is a tool which controls the generation of executables and other non-source files of a program from the program's source files. 
View the page: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/ to use this tool.